# Stack Overflow site shows a mobile version on desktop

Tags: support

I use Safari on macOS Mojave Version 10.14

When I browse Stack Overflow, it shows a mobile version. I tried to switch to Safari private mode, it's working fine.

All other website displays a desktop version, even Stack Exchange and other sites.

Is there an account-specific option? Or site-specific maybe?

I might have to ask on `ask different` site since it might be caused by Safari, but since other sites are working properly, I asked here first.

Comment: That simple! Yes, it solved my problem and it's a duplicate. Thank you.